# understanding 2-d arrays in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, 2d

I'm trying to write a web-based curve fitting program for my students.  In order to do this I need to understand how 2D arrays (arrays of arrays) work in javascript, and it is pretty clear that I don't.  In the code below, I expect the two loops that write to the console to give the same result, but they don't.  The first one gives what I expect.  The second one is mysterious to me.  It gives the same result as a simple `console.log(q);`

Just to be clear, the solution provided in [Copying array by value in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript) does not work.  If I create the array c, then create q by

```
var q = c.slice();
```

when I compute the inverse of the matrix c, I find that q has also been inverted.  I need to have both the inverted and uninverted versions of the matrix handy...

```js
var q = [];
var c = [];
var row = [];

// create the array q
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    row.push(0);
}
for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    q.push(row);
}

// create the array c
c.push([1, 2, 5, 1]);
c.push([3, -4, 3, -2]);
c.push([4, 3, 2, -1]);
c.push([1, -2, -4, -1]);

for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
        q[i][j] = c[i][j];
        console.log(q[i][j]);
    }
}
console.log('-------------------------')
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
    console.log(q[i][j]);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

You're initializing every position with the same array `row` in memory.

An alternative is to initialize with a new array for each iteration.

```js
var q = [];
var c = [];

for (i=0; i<4; i++) {
    q.push(new Array(4).fill(0));
}

// create the array c
c.push([1, 2, 5, 1]);
c.push([3, -4, 3, -2]);
c.push([4, 3, 2, -1]);
c.push([1, -2, -4, -1]);

for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
        q[i][j] = c[i][j];
        console.log(q[i][j]);
    }
}
console.log('-------------------------')
for (var i=0; i<4; i++) {
    for (var j=0; j<4; j++) {
    console.log(q[i][j]);
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks.  It's hard to remember that EVERY time you deal with an array object, you are dealing with a reference, and never the values...

Answer (score 0):

There is no real 2d array in js. 2d just means that the array contains *references* to other arrays. In your case however, youve got only one "row". And then you put references to that one row a few times into the outer array.

```
  row = [0, 0, 0, 0]
  q = [row, row, row, row];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your reference assignments.  Note that you've pushed the same row object on to q four times.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are passed by reference so each time you modify `row` you are changing same array. You can create shallow copy using `slice()` method.

```js
var q = [];
var c = [];
var row = [];

// create the array q
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  row.push(0);
}
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  q.push(row.slice());
}

// create the array c
c.push([1, 2, 5, 1]);
c.push([3, -4, 3, -2]);
c.push([4, 3, 2, -1]);
c.push([1, -2, -4, -1]);

for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    q[i][j] = c[i][j];
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(q))
console.log(JSON.stringify(c))
```